# mysql count performing oddly?

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
# Write your MySQL query statement below
with first_orders as (
    select * from Delivery
    WHERE (customer_id, order_date) in (select customer_id, MIN(order_date)
    from Delivery
    group by customer_id)
), immediate_orders as (
    select *
    from Delivery
    where order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date
    and (delivery_id, customer_id) IN (select delivery_id, customer_id from first_orders)
)
select * from first_orders
```

and this is the output:

```
Output
| delivery_id | customer_id | order_date | customer_pref_delivery_date |
| ----------- | ----------- | ---------- | --------------------------- |
| 1           | 1           | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-02                  |
| 2           | 2           | 2019-08-02 | 2019-08-02                  |
| 5           | 3           | 2019-08-21 | 2019-08-22                  |
| 7           | 4           | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09                  |
| 8           | 4           | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-11                  |
```

but the count returns 4:

```
# Write your MySQL query statement below
with first_orders as (
    select * from Delivery
    WHERE (customer_id, order_date) in (select customer_id, MIN(order_date)
    from Delivery
    group by customer_id)
), immediate_orders as (
    select *
    from Delivery
    where order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date
    and (delivery_id, customer_id) IN (select delivery_id, customer_id from first_orders)
)
select count(*) from first_orders
```

and the return value:

Output

```
| count(*) |
| -------- |
| 4        |
```

What is going on?

Comment: please make a full [mre] so that we can reproduce your problem and which version of mysql ae you using

Comment: Why are you surprised?  `first_orders` returns the first order for each customer_id.  There are 4 such records, since there are 4 customer_ids.  `immediate_orders` is pointless; it isn't used here.  What answer did you expect?

Comment: @TimRoberts, `first_orders` returns all rows matching the date of the first order for each of the customer id's. In cases of ties, this can return more than one row per customer. Look at the result shown above, there are two rows for customer id 4 with the same order date.

Comment: I tested but I cannot reproduce the unexpected count. I get a count of 5. https://dbfiddle.uk/7YEZ4S7g You need to show a reproducible example of test data that gives the unexpected count.

Comment: Sorry, I was fooled by the false indentation and missed that the GROUP BY is part of the WHERE clause.  I also get 5 in sqlite3.

Comment: `group by customer_id` --> 0nly 4 distinct values.